# Reading JSON file content in LINUX

Tags: json, linux

Dears,

Can someone help me out reading the content of JSON file in **LINUX** machine without using **JQ, Python & Ruby**. Looking for purely ***SHELL*** scripting. We need to iterate the values if multiple records found. In the below case we have 2 set of records, which needs to iterated.

```
    {
  "version": [
    "sessionrestore",1
  ],
  "windows": [
    {
      "tabs": [
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "url": "http://orf.at/#/stories/2.../" (http://orf.at/#/stories/2.../%27) ,
              "title": "news.ORF.at",
              "charset": "UTF-8",
              "ID": 9588,
              "docshellID": 298,
              "docIdentifier": 10062,
              "persist": true
            },
             {
              "url": "http://oracle.at/#/stories/2.../" (http://oracle.at/#/stories/2.../%27) ,
              "title": "news.at",
              "charset": "UTF-8",
              "ID": 9589,
              "docshellID": 288,
              "docIdentifier": 00062,
              "persist": false
            }
            ]

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean something like cURL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: The JSON file will be put into a LINUX machine folder, from there we need to read the contents